# Avoid null-Checking loaded .obj-models in Three.js

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

I am using three.js in an Angular project.
I want to load a simple .obj file and move it on the canvas.

The code works fine; however I have to do explicitly do a null check in my animate()-function, to see whether or not the model has been loaded yet. 
Without the null-check, the console will log the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of null
>       at TestComponent.animate (test.component.ts:71)

I suppose that's because the instance-reference has not been set yet because at this point the OBJLoader is still busy loading the resource.

Minimal verfiable example:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OBJLoader2 } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js';
import { MtlObjBridge } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/obj2/bridge/MtlObjBridge.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('rendererContainer') rendererContainer: ElementRef;

  renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  scene = null;
  camera = null;
  mesh = null;
  loader = null;
  female = null;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.init();
    this.animate();
  }

  init() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.rendererContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff));

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      1,
      10000
    );

    this.camera.position.z = 500;

    this.loader = new OBJLoader2();

    new MTLLoader().load('./../../assets/models/female02.mtl', (mtl) => {
      this.loader.setModelName('female02');
      this.loader.setLogging(true, true);
      this.loader.addMaterials(
        MtlObjBridge.addMaterialsFromMtlLoader(mtl),
        true
      );
      this.loader.load(
        './../../assets/models/female02.obj',
        (object3d) => {
          this.female = object3d;
          this.scene.add(object3d);
        },
        null,
        null,
        null
      );
    });
  }

  animate() {
    if (this.female != null) { //explicit null-Check necessary
      if (this.female.position.z < 250) {
        this.female.translateZ(1);
      }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to manipulate the object in my animation-loop, without having to do a null-Check every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to start animating as soon as the model has been loaded. Meaning you call `animate()` in the `onLoad()` callback right after you have added the model to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you need the animation loop to fire before you load anything, is to replace your references with a dummy object:

```
const nullObject= new Object3D()
let female = nullObject
let male = nullObject
let child = nullObject

//...
function onLoad( trueObject ) {
  female = trueObject
}
```

This way you can expect to have all the methods and members existing, but they would be noops.